# Using Jenkins and Jenkins Github Plugin, how to prevent pushing to a branch if the unit test fails

Tags: github, jenkins

My objective is to prevent pushing to a branch if unit test fails using Jenkins and its Github Plugin.

I saw it works in TeamCity in my previous company, and I believe it is common practice.

However, from [this tutorial](https://www.docker.com/use-cases/cicd), the code will always be pushed to github branch even if the unit test fails, because the webhook is triggered after the git push.

How do I configure Jenkins to achieve my objective? If it is possible using Jenkins and Githb Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

jenkins won't do that for you, github might, or failing that you need a pre-commit hook.

https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Is there a tutorial about it I can follow?

Comment: Git hooks are just code, you'll have to write a small program to check whether it passes or not. 

Certain git repo managers like bitbucket does have this feature built in, e.g. requires 1 successful build before you can merge. hmm, this might be what your looking for https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-status-checks/